# How to update podCIDR for Kubernetes master node without recreating it

Tags: kubernetes, cidr

I have installed a Kuberntes system with one node,the node itself worked as both **work node** and **master node**,now I met a problem:

When the pod num exceed 255,Kubernetes will failed to deplopy it,after checking the node it shows there is no available IP address
[image]

After checking the config,I found it was caused by the node's **podCIDR** configuration,the value is **10.244.0.0/24**

[image]

The available subnet number is **254**,which cause the problem.

I did a lot of search, all of them said I need to delete the old node and use `kube init` to create a new node,but I only have one node,if I delete it,my data will also lost.

I am wondering if there is a solution to **update the exists node's podCIDR without recreating it?**,thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Without doing **kubeadm init** you can change the pod cidr of a specific node via **--pod-cidr parameter** in kubelet config file in **/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml**. And then you can restart kubelet via **systemctl restart kubelet.service**. Official docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/kubelet-integration/).

Comment: @VeeraNagireddy Hi, Veera,thank you for your reply, I have saw your answer on other similar question,and before I posting this question,I have tried with your solution,but it doesn't work

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Do not know why someone want to close my question,could you leave a message for why to close it?